# how to make length rule for one net shorter than other (DDR3)

Tags: altium, ddr3

I am doing layout for a DDR3 (1333MHz speed type).
In the layout guideline of the processor it sayst that the adress/controll signals needs to be 40 picoseconds shorter than the CLK signal.

Is is posible in Altium to make a length-rule rule that states that one netclass(adress/controll) should be 40ps shorter than another netclass(clk)?
How would this be done? custom query or something?

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is to set the distance manually for each group, make a group for clocks, address and data.

My suggestion would be to create a DDR3 class, a clock class, an address class, and a data class. If you have channels then create a clock class, address class and data class for each channel. Set the delay tolerance for each class.

Then go through and set the matched length rules for each class (ie address would have a 20ps match length.

I prefer to not use additional rules than this and just select each class in the PCB window and then select each class and route them one at a time.
Here is an example of this for DDR4:
[image]

Using the scheme above also allows you to easily select all the signals and match them based off of length. The closer match the better

The master clocks should be first on the list, then the address group (command address control) and then finally data. You can then go through each class individually and match them internally (as well as highlight them on the PCB)

Here is a great diagram to show matching for DDR3, but it works well for DDR4 also.
[image]
Source: https://fedevel.com/blog/ddr3-length-matching-rules

If you did want to

Comment: So I am not sure I follow..

Comment: So then you match the clk at x mil. let's say 500 mil. then manually you match the address to a maximum of 500-5=495mil(according to the image). And then data also at maximum 500-5=495 mil?   Only length rules within groups but never between groups?correct?    "ie address would have a 20ps match length."   you mean 25ps according to you image?

Comment: I was going to comment on that. You could create a class that is CLK to ADDR, and set that to X ps so you would have X ps between them, but that will only give you ±tolerances, the clocks have to come first so you could get into a situation where it shows up good in the signal lengths but the address could be ahead of the clock.  I matched my whole design to within 50mil, but put the clocks first. The clock signal has to get there first, then command/addr then data. so I stepped them down in that order.

Comment: "Using the scheme above also allows you to easily select all the signals and match them based off of length. "   but here you also mean match within group?    btw thank you very much for your help!   greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please use the voting system (make sure you upvote) instead of saying thanks. I do both. I select all signals and visually verify the 'distance' between them, I have a target number off sheet that I want to meet. I then try and group them all in that length. Then I go through each group and tighten up the routing and make sure they are all matched. It doesn't matter which order you go in as long as the target length is met. I pefer not to setup altium with multiple rules because I think it can create issues. I would prefer to see the lengths so I do the 'top level' matching myself.

Comment: In the end everything is matched within say 50mil